# "Express.js: Unable to delete values from an array using DELETE request."

Tags: node.js, express, filter, postman

by the way iam developing Api for my font end and using postman to handle different http command  to perform simple to do list in which i have created a array to store information from post and send to get and i want to perform delete to delete specific data! please help

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var arrs =[];

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({arrs})
    
})

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
const  {datas,id} = req.body;
let items = {datas,id}
arrs.push(items)
console.log(arrs)
res.send('value');
})


app.delete('/',express.json(),(req,res)=>{
    const  {id} = req.body;
    arrs=arrs.filter((e)=>e.id !== Number(id))
  res.send(arrs)

})




app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server is listening');
})
```

i tried to use json to send id so that in filter i can use condition to remove array with id that match my json id but i failed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out and the code seems to work. The only thing I needed to change was to add `app.use(express.json())` at the top.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var arrs = [];

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.json({arrs})
});

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const  {datas,id} = req.body;
    let items = {datas, id};

    arrs.push(items);
    console.log(arrs);
    res.send('value');
});


app.delete('/',express.json(),(req,res)=>{
  const {id} = req.body;
  arrs=arrs.filter((e)=>e.id !== Number(id));
  res.send(arrs);
})

app.listen(5000,() => {
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

Then I send a POST request to the server with postman with body:

```json
{
    "datas": {"test": "test"},
    "id": 1
}
```

In the console it logged the array with my data.
And then I send a DELETE request in postman with body:

```json
{ "id": 1 }
```

And it deleted the item from the array.

Comment: thank you buddy your answer is lifesaver

Comment: while working with solution i found out app.delete('/',express.json(),(req,res)=>{
    const  {id} = req.body;
    arrs=arrs.filter((e)=>e.id !== id)
  res.send(arrs)

}) i was filtering string id condition with Number(id) so now it is working . by the way thanks a lot